# Determining row number of chosen OptionMenu but possibility to create within same variable - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, row, ttk, optionmenu

I have the following code where I ask the user to open a text which can include several rows within a section of data.

I then require for each row an OptionMenu to be created. My problem is that I need to do different things for each option menu and apply it only to that specific row in the 'grid'. I cannot do this as I'm creating them all under the same name and don't understand how to do differently.

```
with askopenfile(filetypes=[(".txt files","*.txt")], title='Import', mode='r') as f: 
    data_dict=parse_file(f) 


info=data_dict['three'] 
i = 2
for row in info:
    # Create row in 'table' for each output
    no_1, code, value = row             # Obtain results
    def three( code ):
        c = { "1" : "1",
              "2" : "2",
              "3" : "3" }
        try:
            return c[code]
        except KeyError:
            return "None"


    variablelist = StringVar(self.frame_table)
    variablelist.set("Fixed")
    self.list1 = OptionMenu(self.frame_table, variablelist, "Fixed", "List", "Min", "Max", command=self.ChoiceBox)
    self.list1.grid(row=i, column=6, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
    i = i + 1
```

For example, I would like to create an extra box next to the second row out of three but as the third row is created last, when I try to obtain the grid info, I can only add it onto the third row.

My reasoning for having done it like this is because I don't always know the amount of rows and I didn't want to create lots of lines of code creating an option menu separately each time (even if I did know the number of rows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear, mostly because your example doesn't make any sense. Why, for example, are you redefining the function `three` on every iteration, yet you never use it?

Regardless, maybe the following example will help you. It creates three option menus, associates a variable with each, and has each of them call the same procedure when the value changes. By default this method will be given the new value of the option menu; by using a lambda function we can also pass the row number to the function.

```
import Tkinter as tk

# data for the example
info = (
    ("1.1","1.2","1.3"),
    ("2.1","2.2","2,3"),
    ("3.1","3.2","3.3"),
)

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.status = tk.Label(self, anchor="w")
        self.frame_table = tk.Frame(self, background="black")
        self.frame_table.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.frame_table.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.frame_table.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)

        self.status.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.frame_table.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=10, pady=10)

        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(info):
            no_1, code, value = row_data
            label = tk.Label(self.frame_table, text="row %d" % row_number, background="gray")
            col1  = tk.Label(self.frame_table, text=no_1)
            col2  = tk.Label(self.frame_table, text=code)
            col3  = tk.Label(self.frame_table, text=value)

            # N.B. 'value' is automatically passed to
            # the command by tkinter; we're adding
            # an extra parameter, 'row' 
            command=lambda value, row=row_number: self.ChoiceBox(value, row)
            stringvar = tk.StringVar(self.frame_table)
            stringvar.set("Fixed")
            option_menu = tk.OptionMenu(self.frame_table, stringvar, 
                                        "Fixed","List","Min","Max", 
                                        command=command)
            label.grid(row=row_number, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
            col1.grid(row=row_number, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
            col2.grid(row=row_number, column=2, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
            col3.grid(row=row_number, column=3, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
            option_menu.grid(row=row_number, column=6, sticky="nsew", 
                             padx=1, pady=1)

    def ChoiceBox(self, value, row_number):
        self.status.config(text="you set row %d to '%s'" % (row_number, value))

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you. I use the function three later on, it was just part of this section of code. I will have a look into your code and make sense of it.

Comment: I've got this to work for my particular case. How would I however, get the values for each additional set of entry boxes (upon adding these depending on the option menu choice). I've accumulated several ways of doing but none of them are working. Do you recommend I open a new question or are you able to help me considering your example please?

Comment: @user2063: You know the row and column you put them in, so a simple solution is to create a matrix using a dict or a list of lists.

Comment: I have in my code a list 'boxes' where I have appended each box to it. I am then at a loss exactly how to get my values, please see my latest question on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429379/callback-and-n-entry-box-widgets-not-functioning-tkinter

Answer (score 0):

```
self.variablelists=[]
self.lists=[]
for row in info:
    # Create row in 'table' for each output
    no_1, code, value = row             # Obtain results
    def three( code ):    #don't know what this is for, but if it's necessary later, this is more clean than your previous code.
        return c if c in "123" else "None"    

    variablelist = StringVar()
    variablelist.set("Fixed")
    self.variablelists.append(variablelist)
    list1 = OptionMenu(self.frame_table, variablelist, "Fixed", "List", "Min", "Max", command=self.ChoiceBox)
    list1.grid(row=i, column=6, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
    self.lists.append(list1)
    i += 1
```

Now you have a handle on each of your option menus.

Comment: Thank you (again). When I have these in their rows, how can I see which row (and therefore which optionmenu) has been selected? I tried just getting the list1 grid info but again always get the last one.

Comment: What do you mean which optionmenu has been selected?  all three could have been selected at a time.  You could do something like `command=lambda idx=i: self.ChoiceBox(idx)` and then sort out which one was changed in your `ChoiceBox` method if you mean "which optionmenu was just changed".