# Callback and n Entry box widgets not functioning Tkinter

Tags: python, events, callback, tkinter, ttk

In the code below I need to return all values returned (but for each row separately) but I have tried lambda and failed and I'm not getting anywhere AGAIN.

I also have the callback definition where it previously worked and when I click in a box, it deletes the grey writing so I can continue to input in black.

If possible I would like to add the value return for the entry box at the end of my callback function rather than keeping 'numberwritten' and 'callback'..Is this possible?

The number of boxes added is equal to self.number_boxes and can be from 1 to n.

Thank you.

UPDATED CODE:

```
    self.numbers = [StringVar() for i in xrange(self.number_boxes) ] 

    for i in xrange(self.number_boxes):
          row = (row_number +add)
          column = self.column +i
          key = "%d/%d" % (row,column)
          self.clicked = ([False] * self.number_boxes)
          self.choice_title = Label(self.frame_table, bg=self.mycolour, borderwidth=0, width=10) 
          self.choice_title.grid(row=1, column=self.column, columnspan=self.number_boxes, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1) 
          self.choice_titles.append(self.choice_title)
          self.box[key] = Entry(self.frame_table,bg='white',borderwidth=0, width=10, justify="center", fg='grey')
          self.box[key].grid(row=row_number+add,column=self.column+i, sticky='nsew', padx=1, pady=1) 
          self.box[key].insert(0, "Value %g" % float(i+1))
          self.box[key].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, key=key, index=i : self.callback(event, key, index))
          self.boxes.append(self.box[key])


def callback(self, event, key, index):

    for not self.clicked[index]:
         self.box[key].delete(0, END)
         self.box[key].config(fg='black')
         self.clicked[index] = True

         print self.box[key].get()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least a couple of choices. For one, you can store store the entry widgets in a dict or list of lists, then pass the index into the callback.  For example:

```
self.box = {}
for i in xrange(self.number_boxes):
    row = row_number+add
    column = self.column+i
    key = "%d/%d" % (row,column)
    ...
    self.box[key] = Entry(...)
    self.box[key].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, key=key: self.callback(event, key))
```

**The important thing is to not just pick a method somebody gives you on the internet, but to understand the problem and the tools you have to solve it**. If you take the time to learn how lambda works (or [functools.partial](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial)) and have a basic understanding of fundamental data structures like lists and dicts, problems like this will cease to be stumbling blocks.

Comment: I think the '1' needs to be 'i' otherwise the row, column doesn't work out. I've simply done following that 'print self.box[key].get()' but need to look into getting rid of the default grey text as in the callback.

Comment: See updated code where I've attempted at clearing the box and then reading the new value inserted by user. I only managed to clear the box and print an empty line (since the box is now empty). How do I get it to wait or something similar?

Comment: @user2063: "getting it to wait" makes no sense in the context of a GUI. What should it wait for? And what should it do whenever it's done waiting? GUIs don't typically wait, except for traditional blocking dialogs. Plus, comments on this site aren't for asking further questions, comments should only be used to ask for clarification.

Comment: I asked in my original question here on help to try and merge callback and numberwritten. I have tried again myself and it's not working. I wish to erase the default text (done) but cannot then print the value entered by the user following this in the way that I have done above.

Comment: @user2063: what you say is very confusing. Of course you can't print the value -- you just deleted it. Are you wanting to print each character as the user types? While the text of your question mentions a `numberwritten` method, it's nowhere to be seen in your example so I don't know what it does. Stackoverflow is designed for you to ask single, specific questions, not to carry on a conversation.

Comment: Sorry. it's because I deleted the numberwritten when trying to print as the user types in the same callback.

Answer (score 0):

For python newbies (like me) who are confused by this line

```
self.numbers = [StringVar() for i in xrange(self.number_boxes) ]
```

The keyword to google is 'list comprehension', this is a way to initialize a list in the format

> [ expression for-clause ]

which is equivalent to the snippet

```
self.numbers = []
for i in xrange(self.number_boxes)
    self.numbers.append(StringVar())
```

In other words it creates a list initialized as

```
[ StringVar, StringVar, StringVar, StringVar, ... ]
```

whose values are set later.